# jQuery how to take the href of a link in a child element and use it somewhere else

Tags: jquery, parent-child

My page has a link at the bottom which I've assigned an ID to...

```
<a id="nbwalink" class="learn-more">
  Learn more
</a>
```

Above this, there is an RSS feed I am inserting into the page that outputs it's first link as...

```
<div id="rssincl-box-767647">
  <div class="rssincl-content">
    <div class="rssincl-entry">
      <p class="rssincl-itemtitle">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://something.com/somesubfolder/somepage.html">
          Description of Link
        </a>
      </p>

...you get the idea.
```

I was trying to use jQuery like this...

```
var nbwahref = $('.rssincl-itemtitle').children('p').eq(0).attr('href');
$('#nbwalink').attr('href',nbwahref);
```

...to steal the link from the RSS link and apply it the the Learn More button.  Is there a way to do this, I can't get it to work?  =T

Comment: what happens? fiddle please.

Comment: `.children('p').eq(0)` gets a `<p>`, which doesn't exist nor has no `href`. Try `var nbwahref = $('.rssincl-itemtitle a').eq(0).attr('href');`.

Comment: I saw the P tag right after I posted this.  *facepalm*

Comment: The comment under my original post by Pietu1998 was what I used and it worked.  ALSO this was an issue because I was using the dollar sign to prepend jQuery in Wordpress which does not work and I did not mention.  Wordpress requires jQuery to actually be prepended with "jQuery" before any jQuery functions.

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var nbwahref = jQuery('.rssincl-itemtitle a').eq(0).attr('href');
        jQuery('#nbwalink').attr('href',nbwahref);
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong because `p` is not a child of `rssincl-itemtitle` element, `p` is the `rssincl-itemtitle` element, you need to find the child of `p` element

```
var nbwahref = $('.rssincl-content .rssincl-itemtitle:first a').attr('href');
$('#nbwalink').attr('href',nbwahref);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're tring to read the `href` from a `p` element — one that doesn't exist, actually, since `.rssincl-itemtitle` **is** the `p` element and its only child is an `a`) and which wouldn't have `href` if it existed. You need to read it from the `a` element:

```
var nbwahref = $("div[id^=rssincl-box-]")
                   .first()
                   .find(".rssincl-itemtitle a")
                   .attr("href");
$("#nbwalink").attr("href", nbwahref);
```

Breaking down that big expression:

1. Get `div`s with an `id` *starting with* "rssincl-box-"
2. Get just the first of them
3. Find the `a` elements inside `.rssincl-itemtitle` elements inside that one `div`
4. Get the `href` of the first one (`attr` returns the attribute of just the first match in the set)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
var nbwahref = $('.rssincl-itemtitle').find('a').eq(0).attr('href');
$('#nbwalink').attr('href', nbwahref);
```